# Scrabble word finder with pattern matching

Tags: webapp-rec

I'm looking for a webapp which will find valid scrabble words based on the tiles you have and a pattern to match.

So for example, you would tell it that you have "BJEOT?Y" (? represents a blank tile) and that you want to match "O?J*" and it will give you a result such as "object". The ? here represents any letter and the * represents one or more letters.

Answer (score 4):

This seems like just what you need.

[A2Z WordFinder: Scrabble® Letter Pattern Search](http://www.a2zwordfinder.com/puzz/scrabble.html)

[image: This search]

Results in:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Wolfram|Alpha.](http://wolframalpha.com) They have a [blog post](http://blog.wolframalpha.com/2010/04/23/tis-the-season-for-scrabble/) about Scrabble ([`Scrabble koobsa`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Scrabble+koobsa)) and they also have pattern matching (e.g. [`_al__la__`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=_al__la__)) but I'm not sure if it can be combined.

Answer (score 1):

If you're simply trying to get Scrabble moves, then [Scrabulizer.com](http://www.scrabulizer.com) is what you want. Otherwise what you want is an anagrammer, of which there are plenty. Such as http://www.a2zwordfinder.com

Answer (score 0):

The [Lexifind Scrabble Helper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search?q=lexifind) allows you to enter your rack and board letters on a full scrabble board, and can display every playable word, right on the board.  It also has full support for Literati, Lexulous, Wordscraper and Words with Friends.

There is a [video demonstration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ueGJiQc5xl0) on Youtube.

Answer (score 0):

The [Best Word Finder](http://www.wireless-trend.com/wordfinder_best_index_eng.php) can combine multiple search restrictions.

The following link has the fields filled in for the letters "BJEOT?Y" and matching "O?J*".

This returns the word "Object"

http://www.wireless-trend.com/wordfinder_best_index_eng.php?ufname=BJEOT?Y&ufirst=&ulast=&unumber=&umatch=O?J

Answer (score 0):

You could try http://www.scrabbleaword.com too. They have multiple word finder dictionaries you can choose from.

Answer (score -1):

Many sites helps you to make words from letters for Scrabble and other word games. You can use their tools to train for Scrabble, Words With Friends, Literati and other word games, but also to create words with the letters of your choice.

Comment: How does this answer the question?